# Manipulate CSS with the HTML5 Color Input

Tags: jquery, css, html, input

I'm trying to use jQuery and the HTML5 color input type to let a user set the text color of a particular div:

```
<script>
$('#color').change(function() {
    $('#output').css('color', "$('#color').val()");
});
</script>

<div id="output">
     <h1>Some Text</h1>
</div>
<label for="color">Color</label><input id="color" type="color" value="#ffffff" />
```

The above code does not seem to do anything, but also throws no Javascript errors. My guess is that .change() may be the wrong method to use but I haven't had success with any other ones either. Has anyone had success in using this input type in this manner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use .on, I think it's because that colour picker is created on the fly:

```
$("#color").on("change",function(){
    $("#output").css("color",$("#color").val());
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/feL6s/